# Java JApplet just displays grey on webpage

Tags: java, browser, netbeans, applet, japplet

So for an assignment I had to make a little Java applet and display it on a webpage. It builds just fine in NetBeans, but when I try to run it in a webpage it displays gray, like this: 
[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

        /**
         * Initializes the applet PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet
         */
        public static int licznikTextFields = 0;
        int dzienLekcji;
        int godzinaLekcji;
        int ileGodzinLekcji;
        private GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;
        private JButton button;

        @Override
        public void init() {
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PlanZajecJavaProjektApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the applet */
            try {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        initComponents();

                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
         * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
         * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

So what can be wrong ?

Comment: Show the code for `initComponents` also.. And never leave the `catch` block blank. Print the `stacktrace` of exception within it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Gn8btFqK it is code generated by Netbeans.

Comment: I printed stacktrace, and now Java Console shows http://i.imgur.com/voOjuZJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As shown in stacktrace it looks like your applet does not have permision for something that it wants to do.

Remove following line from your code at *line 51*:

```
setStub(null);
```

Comment: But how can I edit code from method InitComponents ? This code is generated by Netbeans, I used design mode to add elements.

Comment: No, I can't edit  this code. I created new project and add one button to panel, and the situation is the same, applet display only grey rectangle.